# java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/config.properties (No such file or directory)

Tags: io, ant, filenotfoundexception

```
  Properties getprop() throws IOException {
       Properties prop = new Properties();

      Properties props = new Properties(); 

        props.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

return props;
}
```

This method is used to load the file and file is placed in classpath of project
and this method is used while getting the JDBC connection.

and after once we build application JAR is generating and that Jar is placed in MDMHubConsole and loding the URL is the procedure.

Same app is working as Just java app,But after Jar generation and replaced in MDMHUBConsole end up with NullPointerException

Comment: You'll have to post atleast some details about your application source code and your ant-code. Information you posted is not sufficient.

Comment: This below method is used to load the properties,

Comment: Properties getprop() throws IOException {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
    logger.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@File load started as stream");
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    logger.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@File load started as stream");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("src/config.properties");
    props.load(fileInputStream);
     logger.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@File load loaded");
    getProperty("username"));
  return props;
 }

Comment: And this method I am using in other method, After calling above method only two loggers 
I am able to see, means load is not happening.

Comment: But once I run in local by using same code by main method, its able to load the proper properties. After once the run this(Its Ant project) Jar will be generating and Jar will be placing in MDM Hub console .
Once after adding Jar and below is the logs

Comment: userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&Getting Conn
userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: ******************Connection establish started
userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Getting prop statrted
userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@File load started as stream
userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@File load started as stream

Comment: userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%*****   java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/config.properties (No such file or directory)
userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  Conn        null
userexit.CustomPostLoadUserExit: Exiting a method after perform True Change for C_HYB_PERS table
f.server.RequestRouter: Request processing exception: com.siperian.sif.message.mrm.PutRequest@331fe190/2240001123000

Comment: Below is my Build.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="HUB User Exits" default="build" basedir=".">
    <property name="HUBUserExitsJar" value="HP-Hub-UserExits.jar"/>
    <path id="classpath.compile">
        <pathelement path="lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="lib/siperian-api.jar"/>
     <pathelement path="lib/mdm-ue.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="classes"/>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="classes" failonerror="false" />
        <delete file="${HUBUserExitsJar}"/>
    </target>

Comment: <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="src"
               destdir="classes" includes="com/**"
               debug="on"
               optimize="off" deprecation="on"
               includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="classpath.compile" />
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="create_jar">
        <jar destfile="${HUBUserExitsJar}" >
            <fileset dir="classes" includes="**/*" />
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="build" depends="compile,create_jar" />
</project>

Comment: I could only go through the ant build.xml you have provided. You should post all these details in question itself by editing it and not post as comments. Content in the comments, specifically code, is not in readable format.
I went through ant file, which looks ok, I couldn't read output properly though.